# How to get Facebook to link to my site instead of my application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have implemented the Like button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) into my pages, along with the proper meta tags. The like text on Facebook is now like:

```
[[User]] likes [[product_with_link]] on [[site]].
```

While [[product_with_link]] takes me to link I have liked, [[site]] takes me to the Facebook application, not to the site's main url. Is there a way I can make Facebook redirect to my site and not my Facebook app when clicking on this link?

Comment: it should be ok, but I cannot figure out the issue without detilas. could you provide a live example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "limitation" of the requirement to have an application when using the social plugins. It makes it easier to track the insights when they are attached to an application id.

To get a simple workaround up and running, all you have to do is have some code similar to this (example is in PHP) on your main canvas URL for your application.

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo "top.location.href = 'http://your.site.com/';";
echo "</script>";
```

Now as soon as a user lands on your application's canvas, a JavaScript redirect will send them to the appropriate page on your site.

Note that this redirection will also happen for users accessing your canvas URL directly.

Comment: I was hoping for a nicer solution, but since Facebook would not give you a way to do this properly, I will use this trick. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @paul! It's true that this is a little bit hacky... but it is the only method I know of that will allow you to do this.